# What are Target rules in Magento EE?

Tags: magento-enterprise-2

I want to understand the Enterprise Edition catalog target rules and What are additional features of target rule module over the CE Catalog?

Answer (score 1):

**Customer Segmentation, Targeted Promotions & Merchandising**

Segment customers into groups and optimize marketing initiatives by identifying specific customer
groups using specific characteristics (address, location, sex, etc.) and/or value (purchase history, on-site
browsing, etc.).
Advanced segmentation capabilities include the ability to identify unknown site visitors. Whether they’re
new visitors or returning customers who have not logged in, you’ll now be able to identify and target
them with special promotions to convert browsers into buyers.

**Dynamic Rule Based Product Relations**

Dynamically target customers to present up-sells, cross-sells, and related products based on their
specific product selections. Rules are easily administered through a condition based tool, allowing
marketers to easily manage specific product suggestions, shopping cart price rules and banners
to any customer segment to encourage additional purchases.

Please refer the Guide

[Magento Features List](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Magento%20Full%20Features%20List%20052714.pdf)